# Getting data sent from AJAX on Express server

Tags: javascript, ajax, express

My code below is sending data across my express server using a AJAX request. I need to access that data once sent, on my express server to do some manipulation. How can I go about doing this?

Express Server Snippet:

```
app.get("/time",function(req,res){
    client.messages.create({ 
        to: "+1" + req.data.number, 
        from: '+166**', 
        body: "This is the ship that made the Kessel Run in fourteen parsecs?", 
        mediaUrl: "https://c1.staticflickr.com/3/2899/14341091933_1e92e62d12_b.jpg",  
    });
});
```

Ajax Request:

```
$.ajax({url: "/time",
    data : { name : 'Justin', number : '662***' }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about the GET variable in the server:

```
app.get("/time",function(req,res){
    client.messages.create({ 
        to: "+1" + req.params.number,  // should be `req.params` instead
        from: '+166**', 
        body: "This is the ship that made the Kessel Run in fourteen parsecs?", 
        mediaUrl: "https://c1.staticflickr.com/3/2899/14341091933_1e92e62d12_b.jpg",  
    });
    console.log(req.params.name)
    console.log(req.params.number)
});
```

If you are saying the response of the server, then:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/time",
    data : { name : 'Justin', number : '662***' }
}).done(function (response) {
    console.log(response)
});
```

I've read the question 3 times, and still couldn't figure out what was being asked, sorry.

Comment: What Im trying to do is send the data through the AJAX request, and then access it in my Express server. Like usually in PHP I would do $_GET for getting transmitted data

Comment: Then use `req.params` instead of `req.data` (;

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to send the data to Express, you probably should be doing this with a "POST" method in your Ajax call. Then, having a route just like the one you have,  but `app.post`. You also should use the ["body-parser"](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser) middleware, before your "post" route.

So, you should have something like this on your server (regarding just what I am saying):

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.post('/time', (req, res) => {
 console.log(req.body); // your data here

})
```

In your Ajax call, just add a 'post' method.

What @joaumg says it's about req.params is also correct, but with a POST seems more correct to me. Your data will be safer.

Comment: app.get is what Im currently using on my express server because it's accepting incoming requests. The AJAX request is within another file

Comment: I know the ajax request it's in another file. My point was: Sending data, specially sensitive data (don't know if it's the case) you usually do by doing a 'post'. You can have another route to the same uri but receiving a 'get'. It also would be more organized.